# Profile setting of browser to be used with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

for mozila we use firefoxprofile class to deal with profile setting. I want to know ho do we deal with chrome and IE to set profile i.e. which do we use to deal with profile setting for IE or CHROME.
Anyone can help me out?
thank you..!!

Comment: I am using webdriver 2.41 with java.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox, we use Profiles.

With Chrome, we use Options.
eg:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--disable-translate");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

With IE, we use Derired Capabilities.
eg:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();        
ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour" , "ignore");
```

Comment: Desired capabilities are also used with mozila and chrome.. right?....desired capabilities and profile are interrelated ?